# Excel VBA - Get parent window of worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Sub that inserts a header from a template and freezes the top row of the active worksheet, which is written as,

```
Sub HeaderInsert(headerTemplate As Worksheet)
    headerTemplate.Rows("1:1").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to turn it into a function which is passed the sheet to insert the header into.  So that it would be written,

```
Function HeaderInsert(headerTemplate As Worksheet, contentSheet as Worksheet)
```

`ActiveSheet` becomes `contentSheet`, but how can I get the `Window` of `contentSheet`?

*Also is a better way to do that copy and paste?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you want `contentSheet.Parent.Windows(1)`, e.g.:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ws.Parent
Debug.Print wb.Windows(1).Caption
End Sub
```

As for the better way to paste:
headerTemplate.Rows("1:1").Copy ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1")

More generally, you want to [avoid `Select` unless necessary.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/293078)